# How to regenerate nginx default config file

Tags: nginx

Using Nginx on Ubuntu 18. I made edits to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` then i deleted it without backing it up first. How do I regenerate `default` file without reinstall nginx completely?

Comment: You could reinstall the package and allow it overwrite the config when doing so, but how you do this depends on what distro you're using... and you didn't tell us what distro you're using.

Comment: Nginx on Ubuntu 18

Comment: Is there no simple command to just generate another `default` file?

Comment: I copied my conf on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ffflabs/bd586e4aa94f2c78ee679dbe05501dbd) it's a freshly installed nginx 1.14 on ubuntu 18.04. Regarding your specific question, nope, there isn't a way that doesn't mean reinstalling.